# Getting user input for the deletion of the desired linked list element

Tags: c, while-loop, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

```
NodePointer deleteNode(NodePointer head,int number)
{
    NodePointer ptrNode;
    NodePointer ptrNodePrev;
    int count;
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        printf("There is no element at list");
    }
    if(number == 1)
    {
       ptrNodePrev=head;
       head=head->next;
       free(ptrNodePrev);
    }
    else{
        ptrNode=head;
        while(ptrNode->next != NULL && count+1 != number){
            count++;
            ptrNodePrev=ptrNode;
            ptrNode=ptrNode->next;
        }
        ptrNode=ptrNode->next;
        printf("Node: %d-%d-%d - %s",ptrNodePrev->next->x.year,
                                      ptrNodePrev->next->x.month,
                                      ptrNodePrev->next->x.day,
                                      ptrNodePrev->next->x.event);
        printf("Successfully deleted");
        free(ptrNodePrev->next);
        ptrNodePrev->next=ptrNode;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Hi I've been learning single linked lists and wanted to do a example about it.Basically i ask user to input how many nodes does he want and then he fills them. After that i ask them to delete a node then they will enter a number which will supposedly deletes the according node.Its fine if the number inputed is not 1 but if it is then i would basically get random numbers. I dont get why it happens i looked through most of the questions about this topic here but couldnt find reason.Can anyone explain my mistake please ?

Comment: Actually of number is equal to 1 the function works correctly. Otherwise it has undefined behavior because the variable count is not initialized. By the way pay attention to that indices in C start from 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually when `number` is equal to `1` then the function works correctly.

```
NodePointer deleteNode(NodePointer head,int number)
{
    NodePointer ptrNode;
    NodePointer ptrNodePrev;
    int count;
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        printf("There is no element at list");
    }
    if(number == 1)
    {
       ptrNodePrev=head;
       head=head->next;
       free(ptrNodePrev);
    }
    else
    {
        //...
    }
    return head;
}
```

Maybe in main you forgot to assign the return value of the function to the pointer to the head node like

```
head = deleteNode( head, 1 );
```

Otherwise the function has undefined behavior because 1) the variable `count` is not initialized and 2) you do not check that after the while loop `count + 1` is equal to `number`

```
    while(ptrNode->next != NULL && count+1 != number){
        count++;
        ptrNodePrev=ptrNode;
        ptrNode=ptrNode->next;
    }
    ptrNode=ptrNode->next;
    //...
```

Pay attention to that in C indices start from `0`. And the second parameter of the function should have an unsigned integer type as for example `size_t`. Otherwise the user is allowed to pass to the function a negative value.

Also the function should not issue any message.

The function can be declared and defined the following way.

```
int deleteNode( NodePointer *head, size_t n )
{
    while ( n-- && *head != NULL ) head = &( *head )->next;

    int success = *head != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
         NodePointer current = *head;
         *head = ( *head )->next;
         free( current );
    }

    return success;
}
```

And if in main you have a declaration of the pointer like

```
NodePointer head = NULL;
//...
```

then the function is called like

```
deleteNode( &head, n );
```

where `n` is some value specifying an index in the list starting form 0. That is if you want to delete the first node then you should write

```
deleteNode( &head, 0 );
```

Comment: Thank you so much as my mistake was i forgot to assign the return value. And also appreciate the detailed explanation.